# Is it a Cloak or a Cape of the Mountebank?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, dnd-adventurers-league

In season 5 of factions activities in the lords alliance you can get a Cloak of the Mountebank.  When I search online all I can see is Cape of the Mountebank.

Did they make a typographical error? Also online it says it rarity is rare, yet in faction activities it says its uncommon.

Can someone clarify for me?

Comment: Total DDAL newbie here, why is the distinction important? Is it less the name slip up and more of the rarity slip up?

Comment: Yes this is very true but their was a small chance that they could have been 2 different items and i just didn't see them on google

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You are correct: it is supposed to be a '*[Cape of the Mountebank](http://www.5esrd.com/gamemastering/magic-items/wondrous-items/#TOC-Cape-of-the-Mountebank)*' rather than a '*Cloak of the Mountebank*' (the latter does not exist).
2. It was accidentally column swapped in the [Faction Guide](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/199498/A-Guide-to-the-Factions-of-Faerun) with the '*[Ring of Mind Shielding](http://www.5esrd.com/gamemastering/magic-items/magic-rings/#Ring_of_Mind_Shielding)*' (which is supposed to be an *Uncommon* item, but is listed as the *Rare* item for the *Lords' Alliance*). Discussed [here](https://www.facebook.com/groups/adventurersleague/permalink/1158487400943479).